# ImportError: cannot import name 'MigrateCommand' from 'flask_migrate'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, migrate

Делаю приложение на flask на виртуальной машине Linux Ubuntu. Появилась необходимость создать возможность миграции базы данных. Делаю это с помощью `flask-migrate`, однако, не могу сделать первоначальный снимок своей базы. Выдаёт ошибку. Ниже прикрепляю код. Если нужен еще какой-то - пишите, с радостью предоставлю. Если будет лучше для понимания кода, то вот, делал по [этому видео на YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poz824J33yg&list=PLlWXhlUMyooZr5R2u2Zwxt6Pw6iwBo5y5&index=8&ab_channel=%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Запускаю снимок командой `python manage.py db init`

Файл `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Configuration
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager

from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Configuration)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
```

Файл `config.py`

```
class Configuration(object):
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://adm:adm@localhost/test2'
    SECRET_KEY = 'my-key'
```

Файл `manage.py`

```
from app import manager
from main import *


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

**Текст ошибки**

```
(ENV) roman@roman-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/flask_blog/app$ python manage.py db init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import manager
  File "/home/roman/Desktop/flask_blog/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
ImportError: cannot import name 'MigrateCommand' from 'flask_migrate' (/home/roman/Desktop/flask_blog/ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что то видео слегка устарело. Теперь flask_migrate обладает стандартным списком команд.
Все тут:
https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: В ближайшее время буду изучать и добавлю ответ тогда на свой вопрос. А так, да, понял что всё уже изменилось там

Comment: Добавлю для тех, кто будет просматривать этот вопрос в дальнейшем. Всё просто, метода MigrateCommand сейчас нет в flask-migrate. Скорее всего вы смотрели по старой серии видеороликов на YouTube. Миграцию так же можно проводить, однако, слегка отлично от того, что показывают в видеороликах 2017 года.